# Remove all projectiles when moving to a different room

Tags: python, pygame

Im trying to make it so that when I move from room A to room B, all the projectiles in the room disappear. At the moment, if i shoot 3 projectiles right and then go left into a different room, the projectiles still appear on the screen until they are carried out of the screen dimensions.

Using the `all_sprites_list.remove(projectile)` function allows me to remove one bullet at a time when moving from room to room.

For example, when i use that line of code, if there are currently 3 bullets on the screen and i move from room A to room B, one of the bullets on the screen is removed but the other 2 stay. Moving back to room A removes another bullet and once again moving to room B removes the third.

My question is, how can I remove all three bullets at the same time instead of the game removing a singular bullet when I change rooms? This is my event processing - i dont think any more code is necessary but let me know if it is.

```
# ---------- MAIN PROGRAM LOOP ---------- #


    while not done:


# --- Event Processing ---

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True

# Controls
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                projectile = None

                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    projectile = ProjectileLeft("projectile.png", 0, 0)
                    projectile.rect.x = player.rect.x-15
                    projectile.rect.y = player.rect.y+33
                elif event.key == ord('a'):
                    player.changespeed(-7, 0)
                elif event.key == ord('d'):
                    player.changespeed(7, 0)
                elif event.key == ord('w'):
                    player.changespeed(0, -7)
                elif event.key == ord('s'):
                    player.changespeed(0, 7)


                if projectile:
                    projectile_list.add(projectile)


            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == ord('a'):
                    player.changespeed(7, 0)
                elif event.key == ord('d'):
                    player.changespeed(-7, 0)
                elif event.key == ord('w'):
                    player.changespeed(0, 7)
                elif event.key == ord('s'):
                    player.changespeed(0, -7)


        all_sprites_list.update()
        projectile_list.update()
```

and this is my game logic;

```
player.move(current_room.wall_list)

if player.rect.x < -15:
    if current_room_no == 0:
        current_room_no = 3
        current_room = rooms[current_room_no]
        player.rect.x = 790
        projectile_list.remove(projectile)
        all_sprites_list.remove(projectile)
    elif current_room_no == 3:
        current_room_no = 2
        current_room = rooms[current_room_no]
        player.rect.x = 790
        projectile_list.remove(projectile)
        all_sprites_list.remove(projectile)
    elif current_room_no == 2:
        current_room_no = 1
        current_room = rooms[current_room_no]
        player.rect.x = 790
        projectile_list.remove(projectile)
        all_sprites_list.remove(projectile)
    else:
        current_room_no = 0
        current_room = rooms[current_room_no]
        player.rect.x = 790
        projectile_list.remove(projectile)
        all_sprites_list.remove(projectile)

if player.rect.x > 801:
    if current_room_no == 0:
        current_room_no = 1
        current_room = rooms[current_room_no]
        player.rect.x = 0
        projectile_list.remove(projectile)
        all_sprites_list.remove(projectile)
    elif current_room_no == 1:
        current_room_no = 2
        current_room = rooms[current_room_no]
        player.rect.x = 0
        projectile_list.remove(projectile)
        all_sprites_list.remove(projectile)
    elif current_room_no == 2:
        current_room_no = 3
        current_room = rooms[current_room_no]
        player.rect.x = 0
        projectile_list.remove(projectile)
        all_sprites_list.remove(projectile)
    else:
        current_room_no = 0
        current_room = rooms[current_room_no]
        player.rect.x = 0
        projectile_list.remove(projectile)
        all_sprites_list.remove(projectile)
```

this is the end of my script:

```
# Load background to current room       
        screen.blit(current_room.background_image, current_room.background_position)


    # Load time to screen
        Timer = font.render(output_string, True, constants.WHITE)
        screen.blit(Timer, [350, 30])

# Draw all sprites in lists on screen
        all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
        current_room.wall_list.draw(screen)
        current_room.enemy_sprites.draw(screen)
        if len(projectile_list)!=0
            projectile_list.draw(screen)

        frame_count += 1

        clock.tick(frame_rate)

        pygame.display.flip()

    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Why don't you just set `projectile_list` to an empty list `[]`?

Comment: sorry im still kind of new to python so im not quite sure what you mean. did you mean change it to
`if projectile:
    projectile_list.add()`

or

`projectile_list.remove()`?

because in both of these cases it doesnt quite seem to work

Comment: No, I mean instead of `projectile_list.remove(projectile)`, use `projectile_list = []`. The `.remove()` method simply removes the element that you supply to the method from the list, so it would remove whatever `projectile` is defined as from `projectile_list`. You can see what `projectile` is defined as by typing `print(projectile)` before that line in your code. Setting `projectile_list = []` is the equivalent of removing all projectiles from the list.

Comment: that does make sense, but now whenever I walk into another room after putting that code in,  it comes up with an attribute error:

projectile_list.draw(screen):

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'draw'

Comment: I don't see `projectile_list.draw(screen)` anywhere in your code...

Comment: sorry i left it out because i didnt think to put it in.. i edited the question to include it now though

Comment: You could wrap that piece of code in a `try-except` block, and handle the error that gets generated with a `pass` or instead just wrap it in an `if` statement that checks if the `len(projectile_list)!=0`, then draw the projectiles.

Comment: @Goose_ it's important to provide [complete (but minimal) examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can copy, run and test properly. It would be nice, if you edited your post.

Comment: thanks for your help, what you suggested did in fact work to a point but a different group of error messages started to pop up. You did help me to understand try-except / if statements a bit better though so thanks for that!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some confusion in the comments, because `projectile_list` actually isn't a list but a [`pygame.sprite.Group`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group). If you want to remove all sprites from a group, you can call the [empty](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.empty) method: `projectile_list.empty()`.

Note that `empty` will remove the sprites only from this specific group. If you want to remove the same sprites from all groups, you can iterate over the sprites and call their [`kill`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill) method.

Comment: oh perfect that worked a treat! thanks for clearing that up, that makes alot more sense now